# How to pass each sublist in a nested list as seperate parameter

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list:

```
lists = [['q','w','e'],['r','t','y'],['u','i','o']]
```

And a function:

```
def func(*iterables)
```

How call `func` with my list? I tried:

```
func(item for item in lists)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly...

```
func(*lists)
```

This basically unzips the list so the contents can be used as parameters for a function.

The * operator is called a "splat" in some other languages.  :)

Comment: Does that answer your question, or no?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Yes, it is answer for my question . thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `item for item in lists` is a generator expression, it's still just "one" parameter. You actually need to unpack your `lists`.

Besides using unpacking (`*`):

```
func(*lists)
```

you could also use a decorator to "utilize" this approach (if you need it often):

```
def packed(func):
    def inner(args):
        return func(*args)
    return inner

packed(func)(lists)
```

I recently added such a "decorator" to a package of mine [`iteration_utilities.packed`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/packed.html):

```
from iteration_utilities import packed

packed(func)(lists)
```

Answer (score -1):

List comprehension must be in square parenthesis so the syntax is not correct.

```
func(*lists)
```

*lists unpacks the list contents so items are separate arguments in your function.